# Does playing a third-party game prevent Steam Family Sharing?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

Yes, [playing a non-sharable game locks me out from Family Sharing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240441/does-playing-non-shareable-games-prevent-sharing). However, does playing a third-party game which only has an icon in Steam lock me out from family sharing? I **have to** register it because I have to play it with a Steam Controller.

The answer linked earlier seems to say otherwise, but I need a clear answer.

Comment: For those who are curious, the games in subject are Overwatch and a Korean client of Final Fantasy XIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, it doesn't: I also have Overwatch and other Blizzard games on my main Steam account, while I have Dark Souls III shared with a second account (In order to fix the covenant bug). Since Steam counts Blizzard Games as being "played" while the Battle.net client is open, and I've played Dark Souls III during that time, I would assume there are no limitations.

This is probably due to the fact that Steam only creates a shortcut to launch the game, instead of having an steamapp entry for it (Like you would have a shortcut on your desktop).

Comment: And yet Steam exposes me playing "FINAL FANTASY XIV - Korea" to everybody else. Great. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can stop the exposition by setting your online status to offline - it doesn't prevent playing, but it will disable chat.

Comment: I know, but it's just tedious to press 'Offline' every time when I play FF XIV with my Steam controller.

Comment: Yeah, steam is really lacking an "invisible" option right now. i'd leave that on all the time. Or even just "hide game played".

Comment: The usual solution is to rename the 3rd party game (on Steam) to "Half-Life 3" or some other mediasexy game. Preferably one that hasn't been published yet.

Comment: @DJPirtu - *"Microsoft Office Word"* also works pretty well